# manipulating several windows in javafx

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8

i am new to javafx and i am developing desktop app using javafx in my app i have many windows i want to have main window that have static menu bar and scroll across my windows by that menu bar and when open new window i want it to fit to my main window just like the project ensemble that came with javafx samples that is very fantastic app.
how to have the top side of my main window stuck to all windows and when my sub windows maximize they will maximize according to my main window not to my main screen .
i don't know if i have explain my idea well but please help 
example : like netbeans ide how it mange several windows and all sub windows contained in one main window .

Comment: Try and follow [this thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2598756). It has a problem statement similar to yours.

Comment: thank you @ItachiUchiha it is not really my problem .
all i need to do have window inside window just !!!

Comment: i found a YouTube video that video solve my problem exactly but the source code are not available 
the video link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0nskbRY-Tnw

Comment: could anyone help me to do like the video in the previous comment please